# How to pass a pointer of struct field in mapstructure.decode

Tags: go

I am trying to decode a map into a struct type with help of mapstructure library. If I do it with plain variable it decodes ok, but if I pass struct field it does not decode the map:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

type Bundle struct {
    Name string
    Struct interface{}
}

func main() {
    p_map := map[string]string{
        "Name": "John",
    }

    p := Person{}
    mapstructure.Decode(p_map, &p)

    print(p.Name) // shows name John

    b := Bundle{
        "person"
        Person{},
    }

    mapstructure.Decode(p_map, &b.Struct)

    print(b.Struct.(Person).Name) // Does not show any name. Blank

}
```

Could you please clarify if I am passing wrong storage for map decoding or it is just mapstructure limitation and I am not able to decode maps into struct fields? Thank you!

**UPD**

I am sorry if I was not clear enough about the actual reason I need to use such flow:

I send HTTP requests to different resources and get various objects with different fields so initially I collect them as `interface{}`. After I get a particular resource object, I need to convert it into a particular struct (`Person` in my sample) so I use `mapstructure.decode()` function for that.

As I have various objects that are decoded in different structures I want to create a loop in order to avoid code duplication. What I wanted to do is to create a slice with different structures like:

```
bundles := []Bundle{
    {"person", Person{}}
    {"employee", Employee{}}
    ...
}
```

And then decode objects in a loop:

```
for bundle := range bundles {
    // map_storage contains different type maps that are going to be decoded into struct and key for the specific object is bundle name
    mapstructure.Decode(maps_storage[bundle.Name], &bundle.Struct)

    // bundle.Struct blank, but I expect that it is filled as in the example below
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must slightly change the implementation

```
var p1 Person

mapstructure.Decode(p_map, &p1)
b := Bundle{
    p1,
}

print(b.Struct.(Person).Name) // John will appear
```

I'm trying your code above but lead to empty `Person`. Maybe `Decode` function cannot change real value of `b.Struct`(I'm not sure the exact reason, this is just my opinion), but if I decode to struct `Person` first then assign to `Bundle` that works.

Updated:
with some research, I found out the problem.You must use pointer instead of struct. here the updated code

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

type Bundle struct {
    Name   string
    Struct interface{}
}

func main() {
    p_map := map[string]string{
        "Name": "John",
    }

    p := &Person{}
    mapstructure.Decode(p_map, &p)

    print(p.Name) // shows name John

    b := Bundle{
        "person",
        &Person{},
    }

    mapstructure.Decode(p_map, &b.Struct)

    print(b.Struct.(*Person).Name) // Does not show any name. Blank

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid I am not able to do it before assigning to a struct. I updated my question.

Comment: @Eduard I've updated the answer also. please take a look.

Comment: Thank you Moch, this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

After changing the type of Struct field in the Bundle from interface{} to Person, It worked for me.

```
type Bundle struct {
    Struct Person
}
print(b.Struct.Name)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use this property as the interface as I am going to set many instances of it with different struct type and then go with it as a cycle